# Promotional rules in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

if want to i buy 1 product of category then sale **20%**, And when i buy more than 1 product of category then sale **30%** for all product of category in my cart.

**Everyone help me, please**

Comment: What's the exact problem? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Ex: i have category for sale. Customer buy 1 product in this category is discount 20% and buy more than 1 product in this category is discount 30% for 2 product buyed in this category. How about do that in magento by rule promotion for shopping cart?